# Elasticsearch wildcard query not honoring the analyzer of the field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field named "tag" which is analyzed(default behavior) in elasticsearch. The "tag" field can have a single word or a comma separated string to store multiple tags. For eg. "Festive, Fast, Feast".
Now for example if a tag is "Festive", before indexing I am converting it to small case(to ignore case sensitivity) and indexing it as "festive".

Now if I search using a match query with all caps letters as mentioned below I get results fine(as expected).

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "tag": "FESTIVE"
        }
    }
}
```

But if I do a wildcard query as mentioned below I don't get results :(

```
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
           "tag": {
              "value": "F*"
           }
        }
    }
}
```

If I change the value field in wildcard search to "f*" instead of "F*" then I get results.

Does anyone have any clue why is wildcard query behaving case sensitive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Wildcard queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html), fall under `term level queries` and hence **not analyzed**. From the Docs

> Matches documents that have fields matching a wildcard expression (not
>   analyzed)

You will get expected results with [query string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_wildcards), it will `lowercase` the terms because by default as `lowercase_expanded_terms` is true. Try this

```
GET your_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "tag",
      "query": "F*"
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation but the latest doc doesn't have that anymore. So how does it works there? in version 8.5 for example?